# What does > mean in comparing vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I was learning on a website today and came upon this code

```
//code removed

vector<int> ans, path;

void dfs(int x, int y)
{
    if (!x)
    {
        if (!ans.size() || ans>path) ans=path;
        return;
    }
    //code removed
}

int main()
{
    //code removed
}
```

In line 9, what does the `ans>path` mean? Both `ans` and `path` are `vector<int>` so I don't know what is being compared.

I originally thought `ans>path` mean `ans.size()>path.size()` but the code gave me a different result. I have searched online for any solutions but nothing came up. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's called a *lexicographic comparison*. Think about how you compare two words alphabetically, well it's the same for two vectors, but instead of comparing the length and letters of the two words you are comparing the size and integers of the two vectors. For example `{1,2,4}` > `{1,2,3}` and `{1,2,3,0}` > `{1,2,3}`.

Comment: Does [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) help?

Comment: [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) are the vector comparisons, and the details are in [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[operator>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) performs lexicographical comparison. The comparison [is described here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare):

> Lexicographical comparison is an operation with the following properties:
>
> - Two ranges are compared element by element.
> - The first mismatching element defines which range is lexicographically less or greater than the other.
> - If one range is a prefix of another, the shorter range is lexicographically less than the other.
> - If two ranges have equivalent elements and are of the same length, then the ranges are lexicographically equal.
> - An empty range is lexicographically less than any non-empty range.
> - Two empty ranges are lexicographically equal.